# Power and ground configuration in a schematic

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, ground

I have a schematic for a commerical circuit board, and I was curious about the following:

```
            1.2V
             |    
------------------------------------------
|      |     |      |      |      |      |
=10uF  =1uF  =.1uF  =.1uF  =.1uF  =.1uF  =.01uF
|      |     |      |      |      |      |
------------------------------------------
             |
            GND
```

What is this network for?  I see that for all of the ICs there is a decoupling capacitor on the input voltages near the IC.  The above, however, appears to just be caps connected between the supply and ground.  What purpose does such a network perform, and how does one decide on the value Ctotal of the network?  They all add up to Ctotal=11.41uF for the 1.2V supply.  There is also a 3.3V supply with the same network, except that Ctotal=11.43uF.

There is also a ground-ground connection I am curious about.

```
 ------------------
 |                |
GND              GND
```

What is the purpose of coupling ground to ground?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the schematics they are put next to each other to avoid cluttering the functional part, but on the PCB they are usually spread out as follows:

- 100nF are placed across the power supply of each ICs.
- 10µF is used for a group of ICs, often only one for the whole circuit, if it is not too big.
- I've seen 10nF to decouple the analog supply, I suppose to be able to use a higher quality C0G capacitor without it getting much bigger.

The total capacitance doesn't matter much.

As for the ground connection, there are probably two separate ground networks or planes, which need to be connected by a wire, and for technical reasons the schematic needs to contain that wire (so it is not forgotten).

Answer (score 2):

The capacitors are called decoupling capacitors, they are placed near the power pins of all ICs to smooth out any sudden spikes in the power rails.

Any switching that happens in an IC will cause it to put noise out on the power lines, the capacitors try to remove that noise.

The GND to GND connection is probably a connection between the analog and digital grounds.